# show in navigation sitemapnode

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm taking sitemapa node and bind it. If SiteMapNode's ShowInNavigation flag false, I don't to show it. SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes does not has ToList method.  How to query this?

```
 SiteMapNodeCollection coll = SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes;
 rptMainMenu.DataSource = coll;
 rptMainMenu.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler for `ItemDataBound` of your repeater you can access the current item instance and conditionalise your output based on your own logic. Or you could filter the data that you pass to the DataSource in the first place. So, something like either of these...

Conditional repeater output:

```
void rptMainMenu_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
  var data = e.Item.DataItem as SiteMapNode;
  if (data != null && data.ShowInNavigation) {
    // proceed to populate the repeater item
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Filtering nodes with Linq prior to binding:

```
SiteMapNodeCollection coll = SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes
  .Where(smn => smn.ShowInNavigation);
rptMainMenu.DataSource = coll;
rptMainMenu.DataBind();
```

Comment: SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes has not contain ToList method. How to write query?

Comment: also I don't reach Where method.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you have the Linq namespace referenced: `using System.Linq;`